# How to remove NA in character data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, character, do.call

I would like to copy the last two columns from each month to the beginning of the next month. I did it as follows (below), but the data contains NA and when I change it to character, the program breaks down. How do I copy columns to keep their type?

**My code:**

```
library(readxl)
library(tibble)

df<- read_excel("C:/Users/Rezerwa/Documents/Database.xlsx")

df=add_column(df, Feb1 = as.character(do.call(paste0, df["January...4"])), .after = "January...5")
df=add_column(df, Feb2 = as.numeric(do.call(paste0, df["January...5"])), .after = "Feb1")
```

**My data:**

```
df
# A tibble: 10 x 13
   Product January...2 January...3 January...4 January...5 February...6 February...7 February...8 February...9 March...10 March...11 March...12 March...13
   <chr>   <lgl>       <lgl>       <chr>             <dbl> <chr>               <dbl> <chr>               <dbl> <chr>           <dbl> <chr>           <dbl>
 1 a       NA          NA          754.00                4 754.00                  4 754.00                  4 754.00              4 754.00              4
 2 b       NA          NA          706.00                3 706.00                  3 706.00                  3 706.00              3 706.00              3
 3 c       NA          NA          517.00                3 517.00                  3 517.00                  3 517.00              3 517.00              3
 4 d       NA          NA          1466.00               9 1466.00                 9 1466.00                 9 1466.00             9 1466.00             9
 5 e       NA          NA          543.00                8 543.00                  8 543.00                  8 543.00              8 543.00              8
 6 f       NA          NA          NA                   NA NA                     NA NA                     NA NA                 NA NA                 NA
 7 g       NA          NA          NA                   NA NA                     NA NA                     NA NA                 NA NA                 NA
 8 h       NA          NA          NA                   NA NA                     NA NA                     NA NA                 NA NA                 NA
 9 i       NA          NA          1466.00               8 NA                     NA NA                     NA NA                 NA NA                 NA
10 j       NA          NA          NA                   NA 543.00                  3 NA                     NA NA                 NA NA                 NA
```

**My error:**

```
> df=add_column(df, Feb1 = as.character(do.call(paste0, df["January...4"])), .after = "January...5")
> df=add_column(df, Feb2 = as.numeric(do.call(paste0, df["January...5"])), .after = "Feb1")
Warning message:
In eval_tidy(xs[[i]], unique_output) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using base R we can split the columns based on the prefix of their names, select last two columns from each group and `cbind` to original `df`.

```
df1 <- cbind(df, do.call(cbind, lapply(split.default(df[-1], 
      sub("\\..*", "", names(df)[-1])), function(x) {n <- ncol(x);x[, c(n-1, n)]})))
```

To get data in order, we can do

```
cbind(df1[1], df1[-1][order(match(sub("\\..*", "", names(df1)[-1]), month.name))])
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Product = structure(1:10, .Label = c("a", "b", 
"c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"), class = "factor"), January...2 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), January...3 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), January...4 = c(754, 706, 517, 
1466, 543, NA, NA, NA, 1466, NA), January...5 = c(4L, 3L, 3L, 
9L, 8L, NA, NA, NA, 8L, NA), February...6 = c(754, 706, 517, 
1466, 543, NA, NA, NA, NA, 543), February...7 = c(4L, 3L, 3L, 
9L, 8L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3L), February...8 = c(754, 706, 517, 
1466, 543, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), February...9 = c(4L, 3L, 3L, 
9L, 8L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), March...10 = c(754, 706, 517, 1466, 
543, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), March...11 = c(4L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 8L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), March...12 = c(754, 706, 517, 1466, 543, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), March...13 = c(4L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 8L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Comment: I want copy column `January...4`, `January...5` and paste before `February...6`.

Comment: @Zizou Can you update your post and show how your expected output would look. It is not clear to me right now. Also it would be helpful if you could share `dput` of your data, so that we can have your dataframe as it is.

Comment: I add image with my problem.

Comment: @Zizou would you like to add only those two "January" columns or every columns before next month columns ?

Comment: each last two columns from each month before next month columns

Comment: Is the order important? I have updated the answer which adds the new columns at the last.

Comment: Yes, order is important for me.

Comment: @Zizou Updated the answer which will give you the data in right order.